Problem understanding samples and ordered samples
I have learned in my statistics course that a sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is a collection of random variables defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathcal P)$ such that they are iid (independent and identically distributed). In the lecture we got told that an ordered sample is one such that $$X_{(1)} \leq \ldots \leq X_{(n)},$$
where $X_{(1)} := \min \{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and so on. How can I understand this order? Does this order depend on an event, say $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $X_{(1)}(\omega) \leq \ldots \leq X_{(n)}(\omega)$? How can I order functions without referring to one specific value/realisation.
We later on used the indicator $1_{\{X_k \leq x\}}$. What does that mean? It takes value $1$ if there is atleast one $\omega$ such that $X_k(\omega) \leq x$?

ConsiderSince random variables are (measurable) functions, there is no canonical order available. However, as you say, we could order them pointwise, i.e., for any $\omega\in\Omega$, we can find again natural numbers $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n$ such that $X_{k_1}(\omega)\leq X_{k_2}(\omega)\leq \dots \leq X_{k_n}(\omega)$. Note that the $k_i$'s are specific to $\omega$. In other words, each $k_i$ is a realizations of a random variable $K_i$. Instead of $X_{K_i}$ the notation $X_{(i)}$ is often used.

${X_k\leq x}$ is short for ${\omega\in\Omega : X_k(\omega)\leq x}$. Hence, $1_{{X_k\leq x}}(\omega') = 1$ iff $X_k(\omega')\leq x$.
